# How to draw Android camera preview

Tags: android, draw, surfaceview, augmented-reality

I would like to draw the camera's preview image , but for some reason it fails.

I'd like some lines drawn on the surface color values ​​in real time.
The code:

```
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Peter on 2015.12.03..
 */
public class PreviewBenji extends AppCompatActivity
{
    Camera myCamera;
    SurfaceView mySurfaceView;
    SurfaceView mySurfaceView2;
    SurfaceHolder mySurfaceHolder;
    RelativeLayout baseLayout;
    boolean isPreview;

    int[] rgbints;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.previewbenji);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        isPreview = false;
        mySurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.mypreview);
        mySurfaceHolder = mySurfaceView.getHolder();
        mySurfaceHolder.addCallback(mySurfaceCallback);

        baseLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.baseLayout);

        //AugmentedView augmentedView = new AugmentedView(this);

        //CameraPreview cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this);

        //baseLayout.addView(cameraPreview, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        /*
        RelativeLayout baseLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.baseLayout);

        SurfaceView surfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this, null);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        surfaceView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        baseLayout.addView(surfaceView);
        */
    }

    SurfaceHolder.Callback mySurfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback()
    {

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
        {
            /*
            Camera.Parameters myParameters = myCamera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size myBestSize = getBestPreviewSize(width, height, myParameters);

            if(myBestSize != null)
            {
                myParameters.setPreviewSize(myBestSize.width, myBestSize.height);
                myCamera.setParameters(myParameters);
                myCamera.startPreview();
                isPreview = true;

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Best Size:\n" + String.valueOf(myBestSize.width) + " : " + String.valueOf(myBestSize.height), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            */
        }

        /*
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            try
            {
                myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mySurfaceHolder);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        */

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {

            mySurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.mypreview);
            mySurfaceView2 = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.mypreview2);

            // camera setup
            //myCamera = Camera.open();

            //Camera.Parameters parameters = myCamera.getParameters();
            //List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

            Camera.Parameters parameters = myCamera.getParameters();
            final Camera.Size myBestSize = getBestPreviewSize(1920, 1080, parameters);

            /*
            for(int i=0; i<sizes.size(); i++)
            {
                Log.i("CS", i + " - width: " + sizes.get(i).width + " height: " + sizes.get(i).height + " size: " + (sizes.get(i).width * sizes.get(i).height));
            }
            */

            // change preview size
            //final Camera.Size cs = sizes.get(8);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(myBestSize.width, myBestSize.height);

            // initialize image data array
            rgbints = new int[myBestSize.width*myBestSize.height];

            // make picture gray scale
            parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            myCamera.setParameters(parameters);

            // change display size
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) mySurfaceView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = (int) (mySurfaceView.getWidth()*myBestSize.height/myBestSize.width);
            mySurfaceView.setLayoutParams(params);


            //ViewGroup.LayoutParams overlayParams = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) swOverlay.getLayoutParams();
            //overlayParams.width = mySurfaceView.getWidth();
            //overlayParams.height = mySurfaceView.getHeight();
            //swOverlay.setLayoutParams(overlayParams);



            try
            {
                myCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                myCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                myCamera.startPreview();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                myCamera.stopPreview();
                myCamera.release();
            }

            // callback every time a new frame is available
            myCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback()
            {
                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
                {
                    // create bitmap from camera preview
                    int pixel, pixVal, frameSize = myBestSize.width*myBestSize.height;
                    for(int i=0; i<frameSize; i++)
                    {
                        pixel = (0xff & ((int) data[i])) - 16;
                        if(pixel <  0x55)
                        {
                            pixVal = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pixVal = 1;
                        }
                        rgbints[i] = pixVal;
                    }

                    int cp = rgbints[(int) (myBestSize.width*(0.5+(myBestSize.height/2)))];

                    //Log.i("CAMERA", "Center pixel RGB: "+cp);
                    Log.d("Center pixel: ", "" + cp);

                    // process preview image data
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);


                    int start, finish, last;
                    start = finish = last = -1;
                    float x_ratio = mySurfaceView.getWidth()/myBestSize.width;
                    float y_ratio = mySurfaceView.getHeight()/myBestSize.height;

                    // display calculated path on overlay using canvas
                    Canvas overlayCanvas = mySurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    overlayCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

                    // start by finding the tape from bottom of the screen
                    for(int y=myBestSize.height; y>0; y--)
                    {
                        for(int x=0; x<myBestSize.width; x++)
                        {
                            pixel = rgbints[y*myBestSize.height+x];

                            if(pixel == 1 && last == 0 && start == -1)
                            {
                                start = x;
                            }
                            else if(pixel == 0 && last == 1 && finish == -1)
                            {
                                finish = x;
                                break;
                            }
                            last = pixel;
                        }

                        overlayCanvas.drawLine(start * x_ratio, y * y_ratio, finish * x_ratio, y * y_ratio, paint);
                        start = finish = last = -1;
                    }

                    mySurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(overlayCanvas);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };

    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters)
    {
        Camera.Size bestSize = null;
        List<Camera.Size> sizeList = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        bestSize = sizeList.get(0);

        for(int i = 1; i < sizeList.size(); i++)
        {
            if((sizeList.get(i).width * sizeList.get(i).height) > (bestSize.width * bestSize.height))
            {
                bestSize = sizeList.get(i);
            }
        }

        return bestSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        myCamera = Camera.open();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        if(isPreview)
        {
            myCamera.stopPreview();
        }

        myCamera.release();
        myCamera = null;
        isPreview = false;

        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

After the draw throws an error:

```
overlayCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
```

Is it possible at all without the native C ?
I hope someone can help !

Comment: always post your error/stack trace, it helps a lot pinpointing where your app failed

Comment: on a null object reference: overlayCanvas = mySurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();